# Errors while trying to play sounds with AudioToolbox in Xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio, audiotoolbox

This is an issue I have been trying to fix for a while. I get an error in my header file with an app I am trying to make for iOS using the AudioToolbox framework. Here is the code:

```
    #import <iAd/iAd.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
    #import <iAd/ADBannerView_Deprecated.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {


    ADBannerView *adView;
    BOOL bannerIsVisible;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;


    - (IBAction)cstring:(id)sender {






    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"CString",         CFSTR ("caf"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);


    }


    @end
```

Also, the sound file is in the Supporting Files folder.

Comment: it might be useful if you could detail *what* the error is

Comment: In the IBAction, it's telling me to replace the curly braces with a semicolon which keeps an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh, I see the problem.

You put your function *declarations* into the .h (or header) file, which is your "`@interface`" while the actual code you'll put into your .m file, which has the keyword "`@implementation`".

It looks like you simply have your code in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks--I am new to using Audio in my applications and I was a little confused. The help was much appreciated.